# Can't install Kubunutu since it says space is unusable. ( dual boot along side windows 10 )

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, kubuntu, windows-10

I can't install Kubunutu since it says my space is unusable.
I am trying to dual boot it alongside windows 10 and I gave it 35 gb storage.
I am pretty sure it is because I have more than 4 partions on my HP ELitebook but I dont know how to solve that problem.

Can anyone help.
Thanks

[Windows disk management image with partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gihb5.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your disk format is MBR (Master Boot Record) an dit supports only 4 primary partiitons. You can check it from Windows Disk management tool by

Right Click Disk 0 on the left  -> select Properties -> In that Volume Tab. You can see either Master Boor Record or Guided Partiiton Table (GPT). If it is GPT, which is a new disk partition method can support numerous primary partitions. But MBR is old and can support upto 4 primary partitions only.

So you have to use one primary partition to create a logical or extended partition. Inside that you can install Kubuntu. Never format or delete that newly created primary partition as it removes the whole logical partition too.

There is another option, to wipe whole hard disk and reinstall everything in GPT mode. I have seen tutorials to convert from MBR to GPT without reinstallation, but I didn't try it yet. Do it at your own risk

Comment: Yes I can confirm that I do have a MBR disk format. Right now I am running windows 10 and I don't have an installation key. I believe my device shipped with windows 7 and then  the previous owner upgraded to windows 10. I would try and wipe the whole drive but I don't want to risk not being able to use a genuine version of windows. Is there another solution that may be possible??

Comment: You can shrink or delete an existing partition and free up space. Then while installing Kubuntu, you can choose logical partition in custom install method.